# External "noise" library only produces identical values for list elements

Tags: python, python-2.7, noise, perlin-noise

I am trying to teach myself how to use the Python external "noise" library that can be found on GitHub [here](https://github.com/caseman/noise). I'm trying to work through the tutorial on the Red Blob Games website [here](https://www.redblobgames.com/maps/terrain-from-noise/). However, I'm not sure how to actually make it do anything. I've read the help text that appears when I type `help(noise)` into the console, but there doesn't seem to be much information available.

Right now, it just prints 50 rows and columns worth of 0.0 float elements. If I change the arguments I put into `noise.pnoise2(nx, ny)` I can get different values, but all the values are still identical. I have checked the addresses of each row in the 2D list I create, and they aren't pointing the same place.

I am just beginning to learn about Perlin Noise, and I don't need it to actually do anything useful. I just want to see the numbers it generates.

*How can I get my code to produce different float values?*

```
import noise

height = 50
width = 50

mapList = []

for y in range(height):

    row = []

    for x in range(width):

        nx = x/width - 0.5
        ny = y/height - 0.5

        row.append(noise.pnoise2(nx, ny))

    mapList.append(row)

for row in mapList:
    print(row)
```

Comment: Your code is working for me on Python 3. Did you try `from __future__ import division`?

Comment: @BrendanMartin Hey! That worked! Thanks! Add an answer, and I'll approve it.

Comment: You are passing `-0.5` as both the `nx` and `ny` parameters on every single call to `.pnoise2()`, thus a constant result is to be expected.  `/` on integers returns an integer (always zero) in Python 2.x!

Comment: @jasonharper I had forgotten about that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're on Python 2, the regular `/` division floors the answer. You'll need to use `from __future__ import division` to get the true decimal result when using `/`.